# zend framework 2 html5 audio tag not working

Tags: html, audio, zend-framework2

I made everything i could to make a simple html5 audio tag work on my zend framework 2 aplication but with no success at all. The audio player shows and suddenly dissapears. This is what i have in my "layout.phtml" file:

mysite

```
    <div id="left">   
        <div class="Status">Status</div>
        <div id="Genero">Genero</div>
    </div>


   <div class="right">
        <div class="Menu">Titulo</div>
        <div class="Contenido">      <?php echo $this->content; ?>

                        <audio controls>
                        <source src="void.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  />

                        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag.
                    </audio>

                </div>
        <div class="Reproductor"> reproductor
```

```
</div>
```

I copied the EXACT SAME code on a plain html file, and loaded it using chrome and firefox with no ZF2, and it worked fine.

I also tried to put the audio tag inside the index template, so it renders inside the layout via the content variable but the result was the same

void.mp3 is placed in the exact same folder as layout.phtml (i moved it there to avoid what i thought was a routing problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is following:

Your **layout.phtml** normally is in one of your modules (commonly **Application**), but after ZF2 renders your whole application everything (layout.phtml; index.phtml) is **merged** into your **public/index.php** - so your html5 player is searching in this directory for the video.

Pls try to move this file **into public** and try again.

Edit: It is not a routing problem, because the ZF2 .htaccess-file recognizes existing files in your public folder and doesn't even start your ZF2.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem. When i had the file in the data/upload folder the route i put on the tag was 

<source src="../../../../data/upload/void.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

as it was merged on the public/index.php it couldnt find the correct route for the file.

But... the problem continues, because my mp3 files are located in data/upload (users upload their songs and are saved there), And when the files are there i cant access them. Is it mandatory to move them all to "public" for being able to access them? I think is not a good idea to store users uploads into "public"

Comment: It's not mandatory, you could create an action, which accept a parameter. You define in that action what file should be chosen and create a stream response like [here](http://www.sasaprolic.com/2013/02/sending-stream-responses-with-zend.html). I think important for this is, that you add the right _Content-Type_. To be able to use this with the video tag you must set the action with param as url into src attribute.

Comment: One last thing. Im almost there. The problem Im having now is that when i insert the "response" into the audio source tag, the player doesnt recognize the audio (now it stays on the page, it doesnt dissapear so its good). This is my "index.phtml" file 

//...//
 <audio controls>
                            <source <?php echo $songstream; ?> >
                          
                        </audio>

//...//

$songstream is the $response variable that is used in the tutorial you linked. 

Im sure the filepath is correct because im not getting any warning.

Comment: I also tried inserting it like this in my index.phtml:


   <audio controls>
                            <source src="<?php echo $songstream; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
                            Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag.
                        </audio>

In this case, the player shows and suddenly dissapears, as the original problem.

Comment: You must not pass in the $response. You must create a route and action which does not return an array, this action only return that response. Then in your phtml you have to do: src="<?php echo $this->url('what-ever-route-is-called', array('param' => 'to-identify')) ?>". This should fix your whole problem, i hope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I had the file in the `data/upload` folder the route I put on the tag was `../../../../data/upload/void.mp3` as it was merged on the `public/index.php` it couldn't find the correct route for the file.

Moving it to `public` fixed the problem.

Later, for accessing the file I followed the tutorial copynpaste suggested and in my `index.phtml` I called that action in the src like this:

```
src="<?php echo $this->url('song', array('action' => 'obtenerSong')) ?>" type="audio/mpeg"
```